# Issues resolving onAction event in JavaFX FXML

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

What should have been straight forward has gone downhill fast.

So far I've tried every onAction related question on stackOverflow, double and triple checked for any typos, and even fell as low as searching on Reddit's /r/javahelp, but alas I have succumbed.

A friend and I are working on a networked text editor as a proof of concept/pet project, and while I am struggling to wrap my head around the networking side of it, I'm trying to be helpful by adding the skin-deep sections, such as this troublesome settings screen. All I want to do is give the user a dialog that allows them to change the theme, which will then load in a new css sheet.

I have the following files:
SettingsTools.java

```
public class SettingsTools {

 String ret = null;
 Stage stage;
 Parent root;
 Scene scene;
 SettingsController sc = new SettingsController();

 public void changeTheme() {
        stage = new Stage();
        root = ApplicationTools.loadFromFXML("/fxml/settings.fxml", sc);
        scene = new Scene(root, 350, 350);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Settings");

        stage.showAndWait();
    }
 public String showSettings() {

 changeTheme();

 return sc.getData();
    }
}
```

settings.fxml

```
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" >
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <RadioButton id="light" selected="true" text="Light">
         <toggleGroup>
            <ToggleGroup fx:id="t" />
         </toggleGroup>
      </RadioButton>
      <RadioButton id="dark" text="Dark" toggleGroup="$t" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button text="Accept"
 GridPane.columnIndex="1"
 GridPane.rowIndex="2"
 fx:id="accept"
 onAction="#acceptButton"/>
      <Button text="Cancel" 
 GridPane.rowIndex="2"
 fx:id="cancel"
 onAction="#cancelButton"/>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

SettingsController.java

```
public class SettingsController {

    String ret = null;
    Stage stage;
    Parent root;
    Scene scene;

    @FXML
    Button accept;

    @FXML
    Button cancel;

    @FXML
    RadioButton dark;

    @FXML
    RadioButton light;

    @FXML
    protected void acceptButon() {
        if (light.isSelected()) {
            ret = "light";
        } else if (dark.isSelected()) {
            ret = "dark";
        }
        Stage stage = (Stage) accept.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void cancelButton(ActionEvent event) {
        ret = null;
        stage.close();
    }


    public String getData() {
        return ret;
    }

}
```

ApplicationTools.java (This is just for reference)

```
public static <T> T loadFromFXML(String path, Object controller) {
        T root;

        // Attempt to load FXML file
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            URL location = ApplicationTools.class.getResource(path);
            loader.setLocation(location);
            if(controller != null) {   
                loader.setController(controller);
            }
            root = loader.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // FXML file load failed, return error scene instead
            System.err.format("Failed loading FXML file at path: '%s':\n" + e.getMessage(), path);

            VBox t_root = new VBox();
            t_root.getChildren().add(new Label("Failed loading FXML file at path: '" + path + "':\n" + e.getMessage()));

            root = (T) t_root;
        }

        return root;
    }
```

When the user selects that they wish to view the settings screen, a new instance of SettingsTools is created, and then showSettings() is called on it. The whole point of what I'm attempting to achieve at the moment is to return a string based on which option is selected. I know that the whole calling show settings to the call change theme isn't needed, but done this way to limit future changes when more settings are needed.

For some reason, FXML/JavaFX isn't allowing the onAction="acceptButton", but all google answers are all about typos, etc.

Comment: You have a typo: protected void acceptButon() -> acceptButton()

Comment: You ever have one of those day where no matter how much you try, you always end up in a situation where you just have to "why oh why am I such a god damn fool"? Yeah, me too